# you tube video not displaying on webview?

Tags: android, html, youtube, android-webview, android-video-player

I'm trying to show youtube video on webview from url . After a long hour its working but still not shown anything :-

**image**

[image]

as you seen above image not shown any thing but seek bar of video increasing (but not shown anything and i m using **API 17 and 480*800(WVGA)**)  and below is my code:-

**Code**

```
movie_image_movie_link.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(act);
//              dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.show_video_from_youtube);
                dialog.setTitle("YouTube Video");
                WebView video = (WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.webview);


                video.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                video.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
                // video.getSettings().setUserAgent(0);
                video.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                });

                String id = StringUtils.substringBetween(
                        MovieJSONObjectHandle.youtube_link,
                        "www.youtube.com/watch?v=", "&amp");

                System.out.println("url => "
                        + Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + id)
                                .toString());

                final String mimeType = "text/html";
                final String encoding = "UTF-8";
                String html = getHTML(id);
                video.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimeType,
                        encoding, "");

                dialog.show();

            }
        });


public static String getHTML(String videoId) {

        String html = "<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" "
                + "style=\"border: 0; width: 100%; height: 90%;"
                + "padding:0px; margin:0namepx\" "
                + "id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" "
                + "src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoId
                + "?fs=0\" frameborder=\"0\" " + "allowfullscreen autobuffer "
                + "controls onclick=\"this.play()\">\n" + "</iframe>\n";

        /**
         * <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"
         * src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WM5HccvYYQg" frameborder="0"
         * allowfullscreen>
         **/

        return html;
    }
```

also try video instead of iframe but still same problem :-

```
String html = "<video id=\"video\" width=\"320\" height=\"240\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoId
+ "autobuffer controls onclick=\"this.play();\">";
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**mainfest**

```
<activity
    android:name="biz.xicom.defindme.controlpage.ControlPage"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
</activity>
```

so if u had face this problem in past so please tell me what mistake i have done in above code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    mWebViewClient = new myWebViewClient();
    webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);

    mWebChromeClient = new myWebChromeClient();
    webView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
   webView.loadUrl("http://m.youtube.com");  // your web url
```